# if you've finished your work (by then)

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, conditionals

Q: What are we gonna do tomorrow at 5:00?

A1: Well, we'll go grab something to eat if you'**ve finished** your work (by then).

A2: Well, we'll go grab something to eat if you **finished** your work (by then).

In both, "you" is going to finish his work in the future. Which is correct? Or are they both correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A2 is simple past tense, and so is incorrect. A1 is a correct option, using the [present perfect tense to talk about a point in the future](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/tensepresperffut.html). Other correct options would include:

- "... if you finish your work by then" (present tense used for a [type 1 conditional](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/)
- "... if you will have finished your work by then" ([future perfect tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/future-perfect/))